# google apps domain verification issues

Tags: html, email, dns, google-apps

I apologize for asking this here instead of Google's forums, but I find that they tend to yield no results at all, ever.

I have a domain verified on Google Apps through `HTML` file upload, which I am currently using for email.

I don't recall exactly how I prompted the verifications, but I got prompted for one about a week ago for another `address@mydomain.com`, and I'm trying to find out how I can void the verifications through HTML, so I can switch to the newer method of creating a `DNS` record.

And finally, is there a way an individual can void unauthorized verifications through Google? For example if someone verified a domain you currently own at an earlier point in time? Google doesn't allow any support contact for normal Apps accounts.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to verify the account or the domain?
What do you see when you go into the control panel?

If you use HTML validation and then change the IP of your web server you might get requested to re-validate.
Best use DNS validation.

Good luck.